# Python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python, int, popen, traceback

I am getting this error ValueError in my vi editor running python v2.6, i cannot update it. After a lot of research and testing I cannot figure it out. Is there anyway to assign a base value of 10 with this current code? Any suggestions for changing and restructuring? If anyone has run into similar issues and has a way they got around I'd love to know for future reference.

Here is my code:

```
    numcpu = sub.Popen("($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'physical id' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
    numcores = sub.Popen("($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu cores' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
    numsibling = sub.Popen("($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'siblings' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)

    numthreads = int(numsibling.stdout.readline())/int(numcores.stdout.readline())

    if numsibling == 0 :
            maxcpuload = int(numcpu) * int(numcores)
    else:
            maxcpuload = ((int(numcpu) * int(numcores)+ int(numsibling))/2 )
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cputool", line 46, in <module>
cputool()
  File "./cputool", line 31, in cputool
     numthreads = int(numsibling.stdout.readline())/int(numcores.stdout.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Your input is an empty string: it doesn't matter what base you use, it can't be turned into an integer number.

Comment: @Evert is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Check the values of the `numsibling` and `numcores` before you use them. An `if else` statement should help you out.

Comment: Convert the numbers separately (not inside the calculation), one by one inside a try-except clause. That way, you can set a default value when the value is empty.

Comment: I don't see how the if-else section is supposed to work: all your variables are still Popen objects, not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the strings `numsibling.stdout.readline()` or `numcores.stdout.readline()` is empty. So when you try to parse its integer value with the function `int`, it returns an error.

Probably you could use a *default* when an empty string is passed, something like:

```
int(numsibling.stdout.readline() or '0')
```

This way even if the variable is empty, you will have `0` in place of an error.

Comment: neither of them are empty though, they both should pull a value.

Comment: @Klyde try storing each in a variable, then print the variable and check if they are empty or not.